# How does Scala's concurrency paradigm compare with Go?

Tags: java, scala, concurrency, jvm, go

I read how Go has made concurrency related development very easy and less error prone when compared to traditional java threading etc.

How does Scala's concurrency libraries compare with Go?  Do they have similarities or Go is still ahead in this regard?

Comment: There is no such thing as "Scala's concurrency model". It's all in libraries.

Comment: @KimStebel I see, but deep down can you get a feel for what I am trying to ask?

Answer (score 2):

Scala does not have concurrency primitives built-in like go but there are plenty of libraries and packages for concurrency. Even with the standard library come [Actors](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/242), which are similar to [CSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communicating_sequential_processes), the concurrency pattern go follows.

Not to forget [akka](http://akka.io/).

Speaking of CSP, go is not ahead of anything. They just made it more bearable and consistent to use. Take erlang for example. They use CSP for a very long time now.